# Android running Wifi Lan and Wifi Direct simultaneously

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I'm building android app. I was wondering if it was possible for a device to maintain a connection to a a WiFi lan access point and to another device using WiFi direct at the same time? I was told that this was not possible in passing but can't find any information anywhere that would agree with this statement. I can find articles about setting up Wifi Direct networks but not on lan and direct. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Multiple connections can't be made at once, I know. But that's possibly not as direct an answer as you want.

Comment: current wifi devices can only talk to one access point at a time, and switching is not an instant process due to handshaking.

Comment: Okay so final answer appears to be: Possible no, attempt to fake using switching repeatedly is also very bad because handshake protocole is slow. Thanks.

Comment: Hey so I found out that Apple Air drop supposedly works through wifi-direct and can operate concurently with a wifi lan connection. Does anyone know why this works but not in android?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simultaneous wifi direct and network wifi is an optional feature for devices. Some devices allow this and some do not.

See the last FAQ question at http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/can-a-device-simultaneously-connect-to-a-regular-wi-fi-network-and-a-group-of

I have tested on a samsung galaxy s3 and it allows both, while the moto G that I tested on was not able to.